# NuGet install FarseerPhysics.Portable package error

Tags: android, xamarin, nuget, monogame

I am developing an Android MonoGame app using Xamarin Android. The project is setup as follows:
[image]

When trying to install Farseer Physics Portable using NuGet I get the following error:

```
PM> Install-Package FarseerPhysics.Portable
'FarseerPhysics.Portable 3.5.1' already installed.
Adding 'FarseerPhysics.Portable 3.5.1' to MyGameAndroid.
Install-Package : Could not install package 'FarseerPhysics.Portable 3.5.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'MonoAndroid,Version=v2.3', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, 
contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package FarseerPhysics.Portable
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

This also happens when I try to install BugSense.Xamarin.Android. I suspect that the error msg is incorrect since I was able to install the same package previously in another project that had the same exact settings as the current one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FarseerPhysics.Portable is compatible with a MonoAndroid project. I can install it into a MonoAndroid project.

FarseerPhysics.Portable only contains a portable class library. So if you are seeing the error:

```
Could not install package 'FarseerPhysics.Portable 3.5.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets
```

'MonoAndroid,Version=v2.3', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, 
contact the package author.

This error is typically caused by one or both of the following:

1. Xamarin Portable Class Library profiles are not installed.
2. An old version of NuGet Package Manager is installed in Visual Studio which does not recognise MonoAndroid as a target framework.

For 1) check that you have a Xamarin.Android.xml file in the following directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile78\SupportedFrameworks
```

For 2) check that you have any NuGet updates available from Visual Studio's Extension Manager which you can open from the Tools menu by selecting Extensions and Updates, then select the Update tab.

Note that there are two FarseerPhysics Portable NuGet packages available from NuGet. One of which can be installed into any project, whilst the other requires the Xamarin Portable Class Library profiles to be installed.